# How to remove leading/trailing white spaces in C without memory leak

Tags: c, memory-management

assume some string(with leading/trailing spaces) has an allocated memory.

```
void s_trim(char *str)
{
  char *end;
  while(isipace((unsigned char)* str)) str++; // trim leading
  end = str+strlen(str)-1;
  while(end>str && isspace((unsigned char)* end)) end--;
}

int main()
{
 char *test = (char*) malloc(12*sizeof(char));
 strcpy(test, "  abc def  "); // <2*spaces>+abc+<space>+def+<2*spaces>
 s_trim(test); // i'm going to use this to get "abc def" 
 free(test); // is this going to free all allocated memory [malloc(12*sizeof(char))] ?
}
```

Comment: Yes it does. What makes you think this results in a memory leak?

Comment: @Jabberwocky, because  the starting point of char* will move 2 step fwd; so what happens to the allocated memory for that leading  2 white spaces ? (and also same for trailing 2). Thank U.

Comment: `*end = '\0';` - to terminate string. `s_trim` should return `str`. But still call free on first allocated pointer example: 
`char *test = (char*) malloc(12*sizeof(char));` 
`char* trimed = s_trim(test);`
`free(test);`

Comment: Your `s_trim()` function does nothing at all. The values of `str` and `end` are kept on the stack, and will cease to exist as soon as you reach the end of the function. The pointer `test` in your `main()` function is unaffected.

Comment: I didn't check what the `s_ trim` function does and/or if it contains bugs, but calling `s_trim(test);` will not modify the pointer `test`, it will only modify what `test` points to (unless of course if there are bugs in `s_trim`).

Comment: Hi, as we can see with your example, they were no memory leak, even though, they were byte allocated after the `\0`, to see why, you can search how `malloc` function works and how `brk()` and `sbrk()` syscall works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `s_trim` does not make any changes in the array `str` and also does not return anything. Any changes in the pointer `str` are local to the function and will not result in a trim of the input string.

To trim, you need to have a return value of this function which will give the modified pointer.

```
char* s_trim(char *str)
{
  char *end;
  while(isspace((unsigned char)* str)) str++; // trim leading
  end = str+strlen(str)-1;
  while(end>str && isspace((unsigned char)* end)) end--;
  *(end +1) = '\0';
  return (str);
}

int main()
{
  char *test = (char*) malloc(12*sizeof(char));
  char * trimmed;
  strcpy(test, "  abc def  "); // <2*spaces>+abc+<space>+def+<2*spaces>
  trimmed = s_trim(test); // i'm going to use this to get "abc def" 
  printf ("Result = __%s__\n",trimmed);
  free(test); 
}
```

Comment: But you did not answer actual question (`is this going to free all allocated memory [malloc(12*sizeof(char))] ?`).

Comment: Yes, because address on variable `test` will not change.

Comment: The original code also would not have any memory leaks. But it would not do the job of trimming the string. The code given above will trim the string without any leaks

Comment: can we access 'trimmed" (printf ("Result = __%s__\n",trimmed);) after "free(test);" ? or need some strdup if needed?

Comment: @yasaramalshan - You cannot safely access `trimmed` after `free(test)`. You should free only when you do not need `test` or `trimmed` in the program any more.